# Admin-ajax is not working?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating one student form type plugin at backend side to insert,update,delete,list data.

everything was going good till I reached to save data to db.I know all process using $wpdb class.I had done this task using $wpdb,but now I get this task do using admin-ajax.

I learn admin-ajax apply in my main plugin file it works.
but I have to call ajax at my other page st_db_process.
where I am calling ajax but it gives 0 output.

here is my code:

my main plugin file:

```
/*
Plugin Name: student management
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.org/plugins/student/
Description: This plugin is useful to add new student data,update data,delete data and list of all students.
Author: Jayendra Manek
Version: 1.0
Author URI:
*/

//Defining Constants
define( 'ST_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
define('ST_PLUGIN_URL',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__));

define('ST_VIEW_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'view/' );
define('ST_VIEW_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'view/' );

define('ST_CLASS_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'classes/' );
define('ST_CLASS_URL',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'classes/');

global $table_name;
$table_name=$wpdb->prefix . 'student_management';

global $student_management,$st_db_process;
$student_management=new student_management();

global $student_ajaxurl;
$student_ajaxurl = admin_url('admin-ajax.php');

class student_management
{

    function __construct()
    {
        //Plugin Activation Hook
        register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array($this,'st_plugin_setup'));

        //menu action and load script
        add_action('admin_menu', array($this,'st_create_menu'));
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts',array($this,'st_load_script'));
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts',array($this,'st_include_class_files'));

    }

    function st_include_class_files()
    {
        require_once ST_CLASS_PATH.'st_db_process.php';
    }

    //creating main-menu,sub-menu
    function st_create_menu()
    {
        add_menu_page('All Students', 'Student Manage', 'manage_options', 'main-menu', array($this,'st_list_page'));
        add_submenu_page('main-menu', 'Add new Student', 'Add New Student', 'manage_options', 'add-new-student',array($this,'st_add_new_student_page'));
        add_submenu_page(null, 'Add new Student', 'Add New Student', 'manage_options', 'sub-menu',array($this,'st_add_new_student_page'));
        add_submenu_page(null, 'Update Student', 'update data', 'manage_options', 'sub-menu-update',array($this,'st_update_data_page'));
    }

    //list page
    function st_list_page()
    {
        require_once ST_VIEW_PATH . 'list.php';
    }

    //add new student page
    function st_add_new_student_page()
    {
        require_once ST_VIEW_PATH . 'add.php';
    }

    //update student data page
    function st_update_data_page()
    {
        require_once ST_VIEW_PATH . 'edit.php';
    }

    //Loading Script & Css
    function st_load_script()
    {
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js','//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js',array('jquery-cdn'),true);
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css','//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css',true);
        wp_enqueue_style('style-css',ST_PLUGIN_URL.('css/style.css'),true);
        wp_enqueue_script('validate-js',ST_PLUGIN_URL.('js/validate_data.js'),array('jquery'),'1.0',false);

    }


    // Creating New Database
    function st_plugin_setup()
    {
            global $wpdb;
            $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'student_management';
            $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

            $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
            id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            number int(10) NOT NULL,
            address text NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";

            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
            dbDelta($sql);
    }
}
```

js code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

});
function st_validate_add_data(){

    var name = jQuery('#name').val();
    var email=jQuery('#email').val();
    var number=jQuery('#pnumber').val();
    var address=jQuery('#address').val();
    var path=jQuery('#st-path').val();



    var flag=0;

    if(name=='')
    {
        jQuery('#name_error').html("Please enter student name");
        flag=1;
    }

    if(email=='')
    {
        jQuery('#email_error').html("Please enter student email");
        flag=1;
    }
    if(number=='')
    {
        jQuery('#number_error').html("Please enter student phone number");
        flag=1;
    }
    if(address=='')
    {
        jQuery('#address_error').html("Please enter student address");
        flag=1;
    }

    var data = {
        'action': 'my_action',
        'whatever': 1234
    };

    if(flag==0)
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            dataType: 'json',
            data:'action=st_ajax_call',
            success:function(msg){
                alert(msg);
            },
            error: function(errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });



    }
    return false;

}
```

my database process class(where i want to call ajax):

```
if(!class_exists('st_db_process')) {
    class st_db_process
    {
        function __construct()
        {
//        check_ajax_referer();
            add_action('wp_ajax_st_ajax_call', array($this, 'st_ajax_func'));
            add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_st_ajax_call', array($this, 'st_ajax_func'));
        }

        function st_ajax_func()
        {
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r("helloo");
            echo "</pre>";
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($_POST);
            echo "</pre>";
            exit();
            wp_die();
        }

        function st_add_data11($table_name, $data)
        {
            global $wpdb, $table_name;
            $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data);
        }

        function st_update_data($table_name, $data, $id)
        {
            global $wpdb, $table_name;
            $wpdb->update($table_name, $data, $id);
        }

        function st_get_data($query, $type)
        {
            global $wpdb;
            $data = $wpdb->get_results($query, $type);
            return $data;
        }
    }
    global $st_db_process;
    $st_db_process = new st_db_process();
}
```

plz help,I stuck in this task last two days.
I can call ajax at my main plugin file,but cant get ajax call at class file where I want.

Comment: Would you please check your console `ajaxurl` is failed or not?

Comment: yes bro its working,but everytime response getting 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer myshelf,
the st_db_process.php file was not loading correctly i need to just put it at top of main plugin file and it works.
It was file late loading problem ,my code was perfect.
this line put at plugin start,and plugin works.

```
require_once ST_CLASS_PATH.'st_db_process.php';
```